# Concat stream lines before collecting them

Tags: java, functional-programming, lightweight-stream-api

Simply, the code below produces a stream of five lines, I need to concat these lines into one line (while streaming) for further use and before collecting them.The code is about to convert a character string into one long binary string

```java
Stream<String> binText = "hello".chars()
    .mapToObj(x-> Integer.toBinaryString(x))
    .map(x-> String.format("%8s", x).replaceAll(" ", "0"));
```

I'm a bit new for the term of "Stream API", so any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Update**: Let say I want map the stream from the above code into `int []` of `0` and `1`, actually, I tried the below code and it works fine but it seems not efficient and need to be normalized

```
int [] binText = "hello".chars()
                     .mapToObj(x-> Integer.toBinaryString(x))
                     .map(x-> String.format("%8s", x).replaceAll(" ", "0"))
                     .flatMap(s-> Stream.of(s.split("")))
                     .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                     .toArray();
```

isn't it ?

Comment: Whats wrong with collecting this into a `String`?

Comment: so you want to have a `Stream<5Lines, 5Lines, 5Lines>` and so on?

Comment: @Eugene, just concat the lines without any coma or space in between.

Comment: you need to provide an example of what you mean, exactly, this is rather confusing: _...while streaming for further use and before collecting them.._

Comment: Polygnome, actually, for some reasons,  I need to merge the lines before collecting.

Comment: Eugene, I want the code above to produce one long line as a stream.

Comment: @FSm *Why*? Why not collect the lines into a string using a joining collector and be done with it? I don't see any scenario where you wouldn't simply collect the lines to get the string.

Comment: Polygnome, you are right, but something is looping in my mind, but it is ok , I will update the answer.

Comment: I have updated the question, please have a look at it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a collector to join those strings and you would have

```
.collect(Collectors.joining())
```

eventually the complete solution could be:

```
String binText = "hello".chars()
        .mapToObj(Integer::toBinaryString)
        .map(x-> String.format("%8s", x).replace(" ", "0"))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: I hope you are right, be the OP says : _...before collecting them_. may be he got the terminology wrong

Comment: @Eugene  `.collect(Collectors.joining()).stream()...` or `Collectors.collectingAndThen(...)`

Comment: @Eugene well yeah, at least relates when the expectation is accompanied with *convert a character string into one long binary string* :)

Comment: @Eungene, nice to know `Collectors.collectingAndThen` , many thanks